# JQuery inserting a layer above existing content

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to have a new layer appear above existing content on my site when a link/button is clicked.  I am using jquery - but the code I have doesn't seem to work as expected.

Here is what I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function () {
  $("#showme").insertAfter("#bodytag")
  $("#showme").fadeIn(2000);
});
```

});

The effect I'm after is to have `<div id="showme">...</div>` appear directly after the #bodytag.  `<div id="showme">...</div>` has a z-index higher than anything else on the site, so it should just appear above the content directly after the #bodytag.

Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Are you saying it is pushing the content that is already underneath #bodytag further down? Or is it appearing behind the content that is already there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear to me that to get the desired effect, the div you are inserting #showme into needs to be position: relative, and #showme should be position: absolute.  Absolute positioning will take the element out of the document flow, allowing it to sit above the content.

Also, two tips - $() is a shortcut for $(document), and you can chain jQuery commands:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $("#button").click(function () {
    $("#showme").insertAfter("#bodytag").fadeIn(2000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks tags2k.

The solution was as you describe.  Adding position:absolute to the content I was inserting did it.  Also - thanks for the shortcuts - I'm new to jquery so this was most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `#showme` has a `position` other than `static`.